# Is there a way to properly drill down into a JSON response with random property names

Tags: supertest

I'm trying to test an API response where key values are randomized alphanumerics. This is making it difficult for me to drill down into the JSON response to get the data I want to test.

I am using SuperTest/Mocha/Chai. At this point I'm just trying to test to see if the property 'id', 'name', and 'pattern' exist, and to verify the values of those properties.

Unfortunately since the parent of those properties is a randomized value, i've been unable to access it.

I'm new to API testing in general, so I apologize if I'm not including some important information. Normally I would do something like this:

Example of expects I normally write:

```
end(function(err, res) {
   expect(res.body).to.have.property('id');
   expect(res.body.id).to.equal(0);
}
```

So far, the only way I've found to do it is to put response.text into a variable, then use split and splice to separate out the data I want. This is ugly and probably inefficient.

Example JSON I'm working with:

```
{ idTag1: 'randomValue',
  idTag2:
   { 'randomValue':
      { id: 'an integer',
        name: 'a basic string',
        pattern: 'a basic string'
      }
   }
}
```